# Why is AWS Lambda failing to reach the FunctionHandler?

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, .net-core-3.1

I am:

1. deploying a C# app to Lambda to the first time.
2. using Mac so can't use the Visual Studio [AWS Toolkit Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.AWSToolkitforVisualStudio2017).
3. using C# .NET core 3.1.
4. deploying using: [dotnet lambda deploy-serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-cli-publish.html)

The deployment seems to work without errors, the Lambda is visible in the AWS Console.

When I test the Lambda from AWS Console log output is generated, some of which is from my C# code. Such as this line "LambdaEntryPoint - init".

However none of the log output in my handler (FunctionHandlerZ) is written to the log.

I see this exception when I use the AWS Console Test facility:

```
{
  "errorType": "NullReferenceException",
  "errorMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction`2.FunctionHandlerAsync(TREQUEST request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.HandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass25_0`2.<<GetHandlerWrapper>b__0>d.MoveNext()",
    "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.LambdaBootstrap.InvokeOnceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
  ]
}
```

LambdaEntryPoint.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System.IO;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;

[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace aspDemo3B
{
    public class LambdaEntryPoint :
        // When using an ELB's Application Load Balancer as the event source change 
        // the base class to Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.ApplicationLoadBalancerFunction
        Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The builder has configuration, logging and Amazon API Gateway already configured. The startup class
        /// needs to be configured in this method using the UseStartup<>() method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder"></param>
        protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LambdaEntryPoint - init");

            builder
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }

        public string FunctionHandlerZ(string input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FunctionHandlerZ");
            Console.WriteLine($"Calling function name: {context.FunctionName}\\n");
            return input?.ToUpper();
        }
    }
}
```

serverless.template

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.",
  "Parameters": {},
  "Conditions": {},
  "Resources": {
    "AspNetCoreFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "aspDemo3B::aspDemo3B.LambdaEntryPoint:FunctionHandlerZ",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore3.1",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [
          "AWSLambdaFullAccess"
        ],
        "Environment": {
          "Variables": {
            "LAMBDA_NET_SERIALIZER_DEBUG": "true"
          }
        },
        "Events": {
          "ProxyResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          },
          "RootResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "ApiURL": {
      "Description": "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am happy to start from scratch with a simple helloWorld style Lambda that:

1. Does not require [AWS Toolkit Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.AWSToolkitforVisualStudio2017), as it is not available on Mac.
2. Uses .NET core 3.1 (there have been some [changes from 3.0 to 3.1 for AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-aws-lambda-supports-for-net-core-3-1/))
3. Is initiated by a HTTP request via API GW and returns a simple response

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Could you please tell me what worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Below is will help you

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler : APIGatewayProxyFunction
{

    protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        // DemoWebApi::DemoWebApi.ALBLambdaFunction::FunctionHandlerAsync
    }
}
```

not required FunctionHandlerZ function

For any Lambda API you are using API Gateway FunctionHandlerAsync will be the entry point.

Lambda Function Handler should be as *[AssemblyName]::[NameSpace].[Classname]::**FunctionHandlerAsync***

Comment: When running `sam local invoke ..` the template that works is the one with Init, but what truly worked for me was this FunctionHandlerAsync as the handler last parameter and simply doing a `sam local start-api`

Comment: I could not completely understand you Bharath. Why 'FunctionHandlerZ' is not required when in the serverless template, it is the name of the FunctionHandler?