# Why AWS Lambda call is not reaching to FunctionHandler?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have a C# DotNet Core application that I am trying to deploy to AWS Lambda for the first time.

I have specified the Function Handler in my serverless template as-

```
"Handler":"TestApplication::TestApplication.LambdaEntryPoint:MyFunctionHandler"
```

My LambdaEntryPoint.cs class

```
namespace TestApplication
{
    public class LambdaEntryPoint : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
    {
        
        protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LambdaEntryPoint called.");
            builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        }

        public string MyFunctionHandler(object evnt, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            //Processing the event
            //This line is never reached
            Console.WriteLine("MyFunctionHandler called.");
        }
    }
}
```

I am debugging with AWS Mock Lambda Test Tool. The logs in 'Init' method are written but not in the MyFunctionHandler method. Even the breakpoints do not hit in MyFunctionHandler.

PS: I found a similar question but could not understand the language of the accepted answer.
[Why is AWS Lambda failing to reach the FunctionHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63812918/why-is-aws-lambda-failing-to-reach-the-functionhandler)

Comment: It is not clear from the question what the issue is.

Comment: How do you know that it's not reaching your function handler? How are you invoking the Lambda function? What was the result of the invocation? What IAM permissions does the Lambda function have?

Comment: I am debugging using AWS Mock Lambda Test Tool. The breakpoints do not hit the MyFunctionHandler method. I do get the logs of 'Init' method printed.

Comment: Don't know anything about that tool, but if you deploy this simple function to the real Lambda service and press Test in the AWS Lambda console to invoke the function, does it run?

Comment: No. In logs I get "LambdaEntryPoint called." and then an Object reference not set exception.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the mentioned `function_handler` signature was incorrect, which is why you weren't able to hit the lambda entry point.

To resolve the issue, use the following convention to define the `function_handler` value:

```
Assembly::Namespace.ClassName::MethodName
```

Assembly => By default, it points to the `*.csproj` file name. However, if you override the assembly name on the `*.csproj` file, then use that value.

Namespace.ClassName::MethodName => These names are self-explanatory, so assume that no need for further explanation

Therefore, to hit the entry point of your lambda function, use the following value for `function_handler`

```
TestApplication::TestApplication.LambdaEntryPoint::MyFunctionHandler
```

p.s. assuming that your project/assembly name is same as your namespace value.

Comment: You mentioned that as per the convention, the function_handler value should be in the format - Assembly::Namespace.ClassName::MethodName. But in your suggested function_handler value - TestApplication::TestApplication.MyFunctionHandler::LambdaEntryPoint, MyFunctionHandler is the method name, not the class name. Also, LambdaEntryPoint is a class name and not a method name.

Comment: I was confused with the naming earlier. Thanks for pointing out, I've fixed it.